# EMU1212M PatchMix DSP App Busted Since Win 10 1903

Tags: windows-10, drivers

Ever since build 1903 of Windows 10 came out, the EmuPMX_PCApp_L6_2_10_00.exe user space program for my sound card has stopped working. I get a nasty error dialog saying "You don't appear to have sufficient E-MU hardware to load the session in your system".  This effectively makes my sound card useless.

Even though the kernel level windows drivers seem to be working, the card apparently won't put out any sound until the DSP chip is initialized.

In order to get a working sound card, I have to revert back to Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.805) of Windows 10 and use the "deprecated" Creative Labs drivers for MS Windows.

UPDATE: This is frustrating because the sound card also now works at least partially in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) [A]

Below is a picture of the error I receive in Windows 10 1903 and later:
[image: PatchMix DSP Error]

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the Patch Mix DSP app for the EMU 1212M working in Win 10 1903 and later versions?
(Right now it doesn't even seem to work in Version 1909)

NOTE: I've tried the Open Source kxDrivers but they don't seem to be working for me either.  I've had the kxDrivers working on an EMU-APS before in older Windows OSes, but I'm not sure I've ever had them working for the 1212M on Win 10.  As I said above, the 1212M *does* work with the stock EMU drivers and the EmuPMX_PCApp_L6_2_10_00.exe app on Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.805); however, it's been broke since build 1903 and I've been rolling back the updates for months now.

UPDATE: Since my EMU1212M is now working at least partially in UBuntu thanks to the help of agkbill, I suppose the next step would be to compare the DSP initialization sequence between the ALSA GNU\Linux drivers and the opensource MS Windows kxDrivers.  Unfrotunately, I'm afraid that's going to be a non-trivial undertaking that could take me months (or maybe ever years?).  I'm not sure my patience (or lack thereof) and other hobbies will let me stay up to that kind of task.

[A] - I'm not sure why, but for whatever reason, the base install of 18.04 LTS Ubuntu did *not* include the firmware drivers for my EMU Card.  Audio would play, but I wouldn't hear anything.  I grabbed ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/firmware/alsa-firmware-1.2.1.tar.bz2 and compiled/rebooted per instructions and then alsamixer worked and I got sound in UBuntu. Thanks to agkbill's post here for that help: 
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-821314-start-0.html

Comment: Creative lists this product as End Of Life and it hasn't received an updated driver for 9 years now. I'm guessing the driver simply isn't compatible with Windows current driver architecture.

Comment: Yeah, but it was working Version 1809 of Win 10 and I can probably get it to work on GNU\Linux.  I think Microsoft did something weird starting in version 1903 so now I'm "up the creek".  Almost makes me want to downgrade to Windows 8.1 or maybe even say goodbye to Microsoft...  The only thing is I don't like the naming convention of GNU\Linux background drivers, but you don't want to hear me rant about that...

Comment: The OpenSource kxdrv3553-full-unsigned.exe (Not from Creative) drivers install in builds 1809 and 1903 of Win 10 and the spectral analyzer *partially* works (and you can even see Windows Sending signals when you test) but there is no sound.  The Creative Labs/EMU drivers work in 1809 but not in 1903 and later.  I'm pretty sure "most" things are working in kernel space, but userspace kxMixer and PatchMix DSP can't communicate with the kernel.  I'm going to hopefully try GNU\Linux when I get off from work this evening.  Yeah, this is bugging me enough to wake me up at 3:00 AM in the morning...

Comment: Ditching Microsoft *is* a good idea.

Comment: Sorry for not updating.  I would rather use the stock EMU Drivers without installing odd binaries from who knows where, but this sketchy hack works on Version 2004 of Win 10:
https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=529349